# PHP Fix get div from url function

Tags: php, function, html, tags

I have this Code

```
function innerHTML($element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ''; 
    $children = $element -> childNodes; 
    foreach ((array)$children as $child) 
    { 
        $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
        $tmp_dom -> appendChild($tmp_dom -> importNode($child, true)); 
        $innerHTML .= trim($tmp_dom -> saveHTML()); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML; 
}

function DOMGet($html, $class, $num = 0, $type = "class")
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    @$dom -> loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $q = '//div[@'.$type.'="'.$class.'"]';

    if(is_numeric($num))
    {
        $arr = $xpath -> query($q);
        $arr = $arr -> item($num);

        return innerHTML($arr);
    }
    else if(strtoupper($num) == "ALL")
    {
        $arr = $xpath -> query($q);
        $abs = array();

        foreach($arr as $el) $abs[] = innerHTML($el);
        return $abs;

    }

    return false;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all, Sometimes when I try to call tag ( for example class="test" ) It doesn't show anything! Someone can Fix the code?

Comment: Please provide a full example of a situation where this doesn't work, and what exactly happens.

Comment: Pekka's right.. Without a full example, it's a little too difficult to tell what's broken.. However, the error suppression operator (`@$dom =`) is smacking me in the eye as a potential problem.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions on Stack Overflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a `DOMNodeList` to an array, it apparently returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It's your m_INNER method thats messing with you. You could strip it to something like in my example and it will work perfectly.

```
function m_INNER($element) 
{ 
    $innerHTML = ''; 
    $children = $element->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML; 
}

function DOMGet($html, $class, $num = 0, $type = "class")
{

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    @$dom -> loadHTML($html); // You don't need the @ declaration here.
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $q = '//div[@'.$type.'="'.$class.'"]';

    if(is_numeric($num))
    {
        $arr = $xpath -> query($q);
        $arr = $arr -> item($num);

        return m_INNER($arr);
    }

    else if(strtoupper($num) == "ALL")
    {
        $arr = $xpath -> query($q);
        $abs = array();

        foreach($arr as $el) $abs[] = m_INNER($el);
        return $abs;

    }

    return false;
}


$html = '<html><body><div class="apa">Test</div></body></html>';

print_r(DOMGet($html, "apa"));
```

This **works**

Cheers